# Rails: tag cloud with acts_as_taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I use the [acts_as_taggable](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem to get a categorization (tag) of my pins, but I can't generate a proper cloud tags, to get a list of all the tags (In fact I have only two differents tags)

in my app/controllers/pins_controller.rb

```
def tagged
  if params[:tag].present? 
    @pins = Pin.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else 
    @pins = Pin.postall
  end  
end


def tag_cloud
    Pin.find(:first).pins.tag_counts_on(:tags)
    @tags = Pin.tag_counts_on(:tags)
end
```

app/models/pin.rb

```
acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

app/helpers/pin_helpers.rb

```
module PinsHelper
    include ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
end
```

And in my app/views/pins/index.html.erb

```
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

But When i try to acces my pins index I have:

```
 NoMethodError in Pins#index
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed the wiki of the acts_as_taggable gem

Edit: 
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb

```
def index
    @pins = Pin.order(votes_count: :desc)
    @pin_count = Pin.count
  end
```

Comment: What does you index action in pins_controller.rb look like?

Comment: You can also remove `Pin.find(:first).pins.tag_counts_on(:tags)` from your `tag_cloud` method since it's not getting stored / returned anywhere.

Comment: I edited my question with my pin_controller.rb index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually pull your tags in your `index` method:

```
def index
  @pins = Pin.order(votes_count: :desc)
  @tags = Pin.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  @pin_count = Pin.count
end
```